# Emacs BSD/Allman Style with 4 Space Tabs?

Tags: emacs, coding-style, elisp

Using this emacs lisp setting one ends up with BSD/Allman style braces but introduces tabs with 8 spaces.

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-style "linux")))
```

How do I keep the Allman style braces but keep the tab spaces at 4?

Answer (score 1):

I don't use `c-set-style`, so maybe this advice doesn't fit your environment. I have in my init file:

```
(custom-set-variables
 ...
 '(c-basic-offset 8)
 ...)
```

So, setting `c-basic-offset` to 4 after `c-set-style` might do the trick:

```
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (c-set-style "linux")
            (setq c-basic-offset 4)))
```

Look at `C-h f c-set-style`. Maybe, playing around with `DONT-OVERRIDE` might help also.